# Java (native) print dialog - change icon

Tags: java, printing, awt

I use `PrinterJob.printDialog()` to let the user select a printer and change various print settings.

However the dialog is always displayed using the standard Java coffeecup icon and not the one from my main window (JFrame).

How can I change the icon for that dialog?

I'm using the following piece of code:

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); 
pj.printDialog(); // how do I change the icon for the dialog that is displayed here

... // process the selection from the dialog
```

Normally a JDialog inherits the icon from the "parent" JFrame, but in this case I cannot pass or specify a parent window for that dialog

I'm using Java6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that a_horse_with_no_name will be stuck (like the rest of us) with a print dialog with no custom icon. :-)

Even iReport's print dialog appears with the standard coffee-cup icon. Print dialog does not behave like JFileChooser or JColorChooser. Fortunately it is modal.

If the icon bothers you too much, you could create a wrapper class around it, and work out the details the way you like.

Java6 API offers no way of modifying the icon. I will live with the coffee-cup for a while  and will wait for the next version of the JDK that may offer a behaviour like JFileChooser.

Answer (score 8):

I have not found a way to change the icon, but here is one indirect way to Remove it.

You need to specify a DialogOwner via the print attributes. This causes java.awt.Window to not use the default Java icon.

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); 
// Create an Attribute set
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

// A different way to bring Up Native Dialog from Java
aset.add(sun.print.DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE); 
// Looks like this class is being moved to javax.print.attribute.standard for Java 7

// To Remove the Icon from the dialog provide an owner.
Frame f = Frame();            
aset.add(new sun.print.DialogOwner(f));

pj.printDialog(aset); // The dialog should not have an icon now.
```

Hope this helps you for now!!

While I continue to search for some way to position this print dialog. :)

Comment: - Access restriction: The constructor DialogOwner(Frame) is not accessible due to restriction on required library /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/
  rt.jar

Comment: What is the code for this for Java 7 since I could not find it. I found a reference in DialogTypeSelection but that didn't work...

Comment: Well, I was looking for another issue but you saved my day thanks to your Native Dialog different way to bring up.

Comment: Read this answer if you are looking at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767621/405022

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution/workaround to change the icon of a Java print dialog (**not** native).

That is, this works for a print dialog represented by `sun.print.ServiceDialog`, for example.

```
public static void changePrintDialogIcon(final Image icon) {
    int delay = 10;
    final int maxCount = 100;
    final Container callerRoot = FocusManager.getCurrentManager().getCurrentFocusCycleRoot();
    final Timer timer = new Timer(delay, null);
    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private int n = 0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Container currentRoot = FocusManager.getCurrentManager().getCurrentFocusCycleRoot();
            if (callerRoot != currentRoot && currentRoot instanceof JDialog) {
                JDialog serviceDialog = (JDialog) currentRoot;
                serviceDialog.setIconImage(icon);
                timer.stop();
            } else if (n >= maxCount)
                timer.stop();
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}

Image icon = ...;
changePrintDialogIcon(icon);
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
pj.printDialog(new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
```

Play with `delay` and `maxCount` values according to your needs. Of course, there is always room for improvement.

Obviously, the `Timer` must be started before any call to `printDialog`. For instance, this also works if the timer is started before calling `JTable.print()` when `showPrintDialog` is `true`.

I'm glad I have a solution for an unanswered question for years :) (at least in my project).