# How to remove Java icon in Print Dialog on Java 7

Tags: java, swing, printing, java-7

I'm trying to do:

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); 
pj.printDialog();
```

and want to change the Java Icon on the modal print dialog window (or even remove it) but I can't seem to.

The following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554452/java-native-print-dialog-change-icon) seems to [answer it for Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331228/39371), but even with the information provided in the following [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331228/39371) for Java 7 I was not able to resolve. I could not find the appropriate constant to remove it.

Does anyone know how to do this for Java 7 specifically?

Comment: Did you try aset.add(javax.print.attribute.standard.DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE), which was suggested in the comments of the listed questions?

Comment: Yes. That's why I linked to the question and answer. It doesn't do anything in Java 7.

Comment: So far there is no 100% way of resolving this, only a solution that sometimes works...

Comment: If you're really up for it, you could create your own print dialog and setting the printer attributes directly...

Comment: I described how to change or, for your case, remove the dialog icon for **non** native print dialogs for a previous question of this same topic.
[**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37243645/1718678) is the answer with the code.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments of the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554452/java-native-print-dialog-change-icon/5331228#5331228), you should try

```
aset.add(javax.print.attribute.standard.DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE);
```

Take a look at [DialogTypeSelection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/DialogTypeSelection.html) for more details

**Updated with Example**

The example doesn't use the icon from the parent frame, which would be nice, but does get rid of the default Java icon from the print dialog...

[image: Without Icon]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import sun.print.DialogTypeSelection;

public class TestPrintDialog extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestPrintDialog window = new TestPrintDialog();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public TestPrintDialog() {
        setIconImage(new ImageIcon("NotJavaIcon.png").getImage());
        this.setSize(200, 100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton printDialogButton = new JButton("Print Dialog");
        printDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                final PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                attributes.add(DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE);
                attributes.add(new sun.print.DialogOwner(TestPrintDialog.this)); 
                PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                printJob.printDialog(attributes);

            }
        });
        this.add(printDialogButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything in JDK 7...

Comment: It all depends whether the Printer service you have on your local computer supports the sun.print.DialogOwner attribute. That particular attribute is not part of the Internet Printing Protocol (IPP). Therefore it may or may not work.

Comment: Because it's definitely not working for me...

Answer (score 1):

The code you specified will only work if the attribute sun.print.DialogOwner() is supported by PrinterJob.

PrinterJob.java is an interface. getPrinterJob() has to be implemented by some printing service class. This class is specified as a system property"java.awt.printerjob". getPrinterJob() simply return a class defined under that system property

```
String nm = System.getProperty("java.awt.printerjob", null);
try {
   return (PrinterJob)Class.forName(nm).newInstance();
}
```

So ultimately it all depends on whether that Class that is returned supports that particular attribute.

You can use isAttributeCategorySupported  to check whether an attribute is supported. Click on "Print" to see the result.

```
 Frame f = new Frame();
DialogOwner dialogOwner = new sun.print.DialogOwner(f);

PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
boolean ok = pj.printDialog(aset);

System.out.println( "Result : " + dialogOwner.getName() + " supported : " + pj.getPrintService().isAttributeCategorySupported(dialogOwner.getClass()) );


// Result : dialog-owner supported : false
```

Attributes that are supported can be found in the link below.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/package-summary.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/attributes.fm5.html

sun.print.DialogOwner.java is not part of the list above. It is not part of the Internet Printing Protocol (IPP). Therefore it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();   
// Create an Attribute set    
 PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();  

// A different way to bring Up Native Dialog from Java  
aset.add(sun.print.DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE);   
// Looks like this class is being moved to javax.print.attribute.standard for Java 7  

// To Remove the Icon from the dialog provide an owner.  
Frame f = Frame();              
aset.add(new sun.print.DialogOwner(f));  

pj.printDialog(aset); // The dialog should not have an icon now.
```

Comment: It would appear you've then the code from the example linked in the original question, which was stated not to work under Java 7....

Comment: I noticed in my code I had missed adding the parent frame but doing this didn't resolve the issue.